# stringstream causes link error?

Tags: c++, std

I have the following class:

```
#ifndef CGE_NET_MESSAGE_PARSER_HPP
#define CGE_NET_MESSAGE_PARSER_HPP
#include "Game/platform.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace cge
{
    class NetMessageParser
    {
        static std::stringstream ss;
        static void clearStream();
    public:
        NetMessageParser(void);
        static int parseInt(const std::string &str);
        static float parseFloat(const std::string &str);
        static double parseDouble(const std::string &str);
        static std::vector<int> parseIntVectorString(
            std::string str, char startKey, char endKey, char separator);
        static std::string numberToString(int n);
        static std::string numberToString(float n);
        static std::string numberToString(double n);
        virtual ~NetMessageParser(void);
    };

}
#endif
```

Which produces the following linker error:

> Error 3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static
>   class std::basic_stringstream,class
>   std::allocator > cge::NetMessageParser::ss"
>   (?ss@NetMessageParser@cge@@0V?$basic_stringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)    NetMessageParser.obj

What could be wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `std::stringstream`. You simply failed to read properly the chapter in your C++ book about how to define static members. There are a hundred gazillion million questions about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare storage for static variables in the CPP file. You probably want something like this

std::stringstream NetMessageParser::ss;

Oh and do not put this in header file otherwise you will get errors about multiple definitions

Answer (score 4):

You have to define static members outside of the class as well or they will be considered external. add this:

```
static std::stringstream NetMessageParser::ss;
```

outside of your class and the linker error should go away.